Efficiently scale multiple redis instances and sync their data
I am trying to scale redis and sync data between multiple nodes. My use-case in not compatible with redis cluster, I need to have multiple master nodes.
How can I sync data between multiple redis master nodes with least impact on performance and CPU utilization and with least delay.
Currently, I have a python script that does the sync which takes about 10 minutes for a single sync. I cannot use redis replication as it is a one way data sync from master to replica. In my case, I have two master instances.
I need to support about 200K queries per second. How do I solve this problem efficiently, maybe there's a better way to sync redis data between multiple nodes?

Would this resolve your problem? https://redis.io/active-active/

@PieterCailliau Cluster will require me to worry about partitioning? I want to write up to 100K keys using redis pipeline in one trip to redis
